How to use GCC Variable in pcf or gosu code in guidewire cloud
Just want to know if we can use GCC variable in pcf or gosu class . I know we can use GCC variable reference in config.xml like
"${GCC-variableName}".
But want to check same can be used in any of pcf file or gosu. Codr

You can access variables using System.getenv()
For example, I have a variable called MOCKING_TYPE, and I can get the value using
System.getEnv("MOCKING_TYPE")

No, the variables are used in the substitution process during deployment but are not documented as accessible via Gosu code or API calls.  Their purpose is to externalize what would otherwise be "hard-coded" properties of the server, not as flags or inputs to business logic.

depending the use case, you could use the Runtime Properties to configure the value based on the environment.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
